# Updating values in mysql in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a android app that sends data to my database. My php query is insert. My question is when i use the update query in php, do i need to change my android code or just in the php?

Comment: Usually the left hand doesn't always know what the right hand is doing, so it's best they both shake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to modify the query in the php web service. And only if you need to send an additional data, you would have to modify your android app.

Comment: I see thank you so much!